# I can't get preg_split to work properly in wp

Tags: regex, wordpress, preg-split

I need to find out how many sentences there are on a page in WordPress. I used `preg_split(/[!?.]/,$text)` to find out and then used `sizeof($array)` to get the number of sentences. I get the wrong number. Seems as the whitespace between my sentences are counted too (but I'm not sure that's what's happening). It returns 21 when it should return 14.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characters `?` and `.` have a special meaning in regex patterns. So I think you have to *escape the characters with a backslash*, so they are matched *literally*.

**For instance**

- `.` normally matches any single character, except line-breaks
- `?` matches zero or one

If you want to go deeper into regex check out this [link](http://regexr.com/) or look [here](https://regex101.com/r/fG9uI8/1).

```
$text = "This is a test. this is. again. and again? or what! is it?";

$num = preg_split( '/[!\?\.]/', $text, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY );

var_dump( sizeof( $num ) ); //outputs int(6)
```

Comment: Thank you, you are right ofcourse. But even so it does not work. There are pictures in the post. Could that complicate things?

Comment: Here for example you would have to remove the html tags to get it work: `$text = strip_tags( "<a href='http:/www.google.com'>again</a>?"); `. In WP you could use the handy function `wp_strip_all_tags` instead of `strip_tags`.
_OR_ perhaps you build a regex which checks if the chars `! ? and .` are followed by *whitespace* or *newline*, to get the number of sentences.

Comment: Tank you! That sorken fine!